# Creating a custom JSON tokenizer

Tags: c#, json, tokenize

I am trying to parse JSON into a token object. Right now Im using JSON.Net to generate a static class, and parsing it using Json2csharp, but I would like to make each array element its own Token object and I'm not quite sure how to do that. Do I need to implement my own JSON parser? I can modify the JSON object as needed.

My JSON Deserializer: `JSONopMap jo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSONopMap>(myjson2);`

```
public class JSONopMap
{
List<List<string>>addr  {get;set;}
}
```

JSON

```
{
  'addr':[['~address'],['removeall','.'],['append',' ','~age']]
}
```

My end goal is to create a MyToken class like this:

```
public class MyToken
{
public enum tokenType {get;set;}
public List<string> parts {get;set;}
}

public class TokenParent{
public string ResultName{get;set;}
public List<MyToken> mytokens{get;set;}
}

public enum tokenType{Map,Append,Removeall,Lower}
```

So I would have three `MyToken` objects like this:

```
new MyToken{
 tokenType=Map,
 parts=new List<string>(){"~address"}
}

new MyToken{
 tokenType=Removeall,
 parts=new List<string>(){"."}
}

new MyToken{
 tokenType=Append,
 parts=new List<string>(){" ","~age"}
}
```

and a parent which contained them all:

```
new TokenParent{
 ResultName="addr",
 mytokens = (the tokens created above)
}
```

Comment: So `address` would be present in only one inner list or may be it can presnt in another lists also?  and same for (dot) `.` and (space) `" "` and `~age` also

Comment: In your json `tokenType` present in each inner list except 1st inner list where `map` is missing with  `~address`.

Comment: @er-sho Yes tokenType is present in each inner list except the first (where the ~ denotes a Map tokenType)

Comment: @er-sho yes, all terms can be present in multiple lists

Comment: I think you need custom JsonConverter that take care of your json and deserialize it to proper classes